# How to parse to Date from String value like '20180131T120000Z'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to parse the String date format(yyyyMMddThhmmssZ) to Date.

```
const date = Date.parse("20171201T120000Z");
console.log(date );
```

Result is ...

```
NaN
```

Could you teach me the smartest way?

Comment: so, you'll eventually want `new Date("2017-12-01T12:00:00Z")` - a bit of string manipulation will do - perhaps `"20171201T120000Z".replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})Z$/, "$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6Z"` - though, there may be a simpler way - like with a library, moment.js for example

Comment: Do you control the source of the date strings? Are those user-entered values? Are they coming from an API/DB?

Comment: The data are coming from some external system as API.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should try to standardize the date string in a way that works best for your needs. As the [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), parsing a date from a string is problematic in general.

> *Date.parse()*
>
> **Note:** Parsing of strings with Date.parse is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

Although your date format is [valid ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) as illustrated in the comments by @duskwuff, it is not supported by `Date.parse`.

It seems [the version specified here by ECMAScript is supported](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, but not a format like `20180131T011614Z` as you are using. It seems Date.parse only supports a simplification of the ISO 8601 format.

A library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is helpful as it can parse a wide range of date formats automatically (including your valid ISO 8601 date) or you can even specify your date format explicitly if you wanted.

```
moment('20171201T120000Z', 'YYYYMMDDTHHmmssZ').toString()
"Fri Dec 01 2017 06:00:00 GMT-0600"
 moment('20171201T120000Z').toString()
"Fri Dec 01 2017 06:00:00 GMT-0600"
```

Though, for your example, you could parse out the date without moment.js

```
let dateString = '20171201T120000Z'
let [_, year, month, day, hour, min, sec] = dateString.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/)
// month is 0-based so subtract 1
new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, min, sec)
```

> Could you teach me the smartest way?

I would say the "smartest way" can vary wildly based on your circumstances.

- Do you control the source of these date strings?
- Are the date strings coming from another system?
- Are users entering these date strings?

As long as you use *some* standard (even if it's not supported directly by `Date.parse`), then I would say the parsing can be done with whatever method works best for you. A library like `moment`, manually parsing the elements of the date, translating your date to epoch or a format recognized by `Date.parse`, or whatever you prefer.

Comment: The format the OP is trying to parse is conformant with ISO8601.

Comment: Thanks @duskwuff. I did not realize that was valid ISO8601. I updated my answer in light of that.